# How can I get all values, which occur in more than 1 array?

Tags: php, arrays, match, array-intersect

Is it possible in PHP to cross check all matches of arrays and store the result to an array? I found `array_intersect(), but this function only gives results of the first array back. And only if the value are in all arrays present.

Example input:

```
Array 1 = 1,2,3
Array 2 = 4,5,6
Array 3 = 6,7,8
Array 4 = 3,9,10
```

Now I need an array which gives me any match back. In this example it would be:

```
result = 3,6
```

Because "3" is in array 1 and array 4 and result "6" is in array 2 and array 3.

Any match which is in more than one array. Any hints/ideas?

Comment: How do you come to this result ?

Comment: So as soon as 1 value is in 2 arrays you want it in your results array?

Comment: edited. Is it maybe a solution to make a cross product of all and then get the numbers which are more than once insight?   @Rizier123: Yes. exactly.

Comment: `array_intersect`, not `array_interselect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

First you get all unique values from each array with [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php). Then you merge them together into one array with [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and count all values with [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php).

After this you simply filter all values out with [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), which aren't in more than 1 array and you have your expected result.

To flip the array back, just use [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php).

```
<?php

    $count = array_count_values(array_merge(array_unique($arr1), array_unique($arr2), array_unique($arr3), array_unique($arr4)));
    $result = array_keys(array_filter($count, function($v){
        return $v >= 2;
    }));

    print_r($result);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 6
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You are asking for an intersection: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

In your case you will need logic to perform the intersection on every combination of two arrays.

Comment: *Err.* I don't think so: *I found **array_interselect**. But this function only gives results of the first array back*

Comment: No, it perform an intersect: results in *both* parametric arrays.

Comment: The problem is that if I have many arrays (for example 14) any combination of those are a lot of combinations.